# Authorize id token using Custom Authorizer with Lambda and Boto3

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a bunch of users registered in 3 different user pools. I want to grant access to users of 2 user pools and deny permission to the other. API Gateway allows the use of id token to verify if a user belongs to the user pool authorizer and grants access by looking at the id token we get after sign in. I wanted to know if there was any way to replicate this in boto3?

What I want to do is receive the id token in my lambda authorizer, check to which user pool it belongs to and then allow access to AWS resource configured in my Integration Request. I do not want to make any  api call from my lambda after authorization. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cognito ID token is in the form of a JWT (JSON Web Token). The `ISS` claim is in the format `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}`.

Each User Pool has a corresponding JWK, which can be found at `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`.

So what you will need to do in your Lambda Authorizer is get the `ISS` claim from the ID token (any decent JWT library should do this) and work out the `UserPoolId`. Then, if it is from a valid User Pool, validate the token using the JWK for that User Pool and decent JWT library. So if the user is in one of the relevant User Pools **and** the token is valid, you grant access.